# Is the angular momentum operator changed under electromagnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect

We know that the momentum operator is changed to canonical momentum $p-iq A(r)$ in the electromagnetic field, and this leads to the change of translation momentum operator in the lattice also.  The result of this change leads the translation momentum operator along the x-axis and y-axis do not commute.

**My question**

Is the angular momentum operator changed under an electromagnetic field? Then the rotation operator may change also.

Comment: Do you mean the Noether charge associated to rotations in the presence of a background electromagnetic field?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the rotation operator in the electromagnetic field.

Comment: Written in terms of coordinates and velocities expressions for (angular) momenta do get changed. However, operators stay the same. It is not correct to say that say $p_x$ does not commute with $p_y$ anymore.  By definition (linear) momenta operators are such that $[p_i,p_j]=0$.